# How can I get data from DAO through the model and append them in the view

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, dao

I am new to Java and I am trying to implement a login system and a user profile conform to MVC - DAO. I would like to enable the controller trough the method addUserDatatoView() to retrieve the user credentials from DAO, in order to add them as strings in a new JPanel (view). Anyway, I am not sure that my way to proceed is correct. First of all, I am getting all the time the NullPointerException, event though the DAO-level is getting correctly the data from the database:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "model.User.getUserName()" because "this.user" is null
    at controller.LoginController.addUserDatatoView(LoginController.java:75)
    at controller.LoginController.showHome(LoginController.java:65)
    at controller.LoginController$LoginListener.actionPerformed(LoginController.java:44)
```

How can I actually retrieve the data from DAO passing through the Model (User class)? What would be the best way to deploy to data as strings from the controller to the view?

I am quite confused about the communication between the different classes and what is the correct procedure, in order not to contravene MVC-DAO.

I am not asking you to solve the problem, but to get an hint in order to get the right direction.

DAO-Implementation:

```
package dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import controller.HomeController;
import ds.OracleDsSingleton;
import model.Event;
import model.User;
import view.HomeView;
import view.LoginView;
import view.ProfileView;

public class DaoImpl implements DAO {

    LoginView view;
    ProfileView profView;
    ResultSet rs;

    public DaoImpl(LoginView view, ProfileView profView) {
        this.view = view;
        this.profView = profView;
    }
    @Override
    public ArrayList<User> getUserLogIn (String userName, String userPass) throws SQLException {
        OracleDsSingleton ora = OracleDsSingleton.getInstance();
        boolean controlRecords = false;
        try {
            //ArrayList type User
            ArrayList<User> user = new ArrayList<User>();
            Connection con = ora.getConnection();
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String addQuery = "SELECT * FROM UserList";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(addQuery);
            while (rs.next()) {
                userName = rs.getString("userName");
                userPass = rs.getString("userPass");
                if (userName.equals(view.getUserNameTextField().getText().toString())
                        && (userPass.equals(view.getUserPassTextField().getText().toString()))) {
                    {
                        controlRecords = true;
                        User u = new User(userName, userPass);
                        user.add(u);
                        for(User us : user) {
                            System.out.println("Directly from DAOImp: " + us);
                        }
                        return user;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if (!controlRecords) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not successfully logged in!");
            };
            if (con != null)
                con.close();
            if (stmt != null)
                stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        return null;
    }
}
```

Class User:

```
public class User {
    String userName;
    String userPass;

    public User(String userName, String userPass) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.userPass = userPass;
    }
    
    public User() throws SQLException { 
    }
    
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    
    public String getUserPass() {
        return userPass;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    
    
    public String toString() {
        return userName + userPass;
    }
}
```

Controller

```
package controller;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

import controller.LoginController.LoginBACKListener;
import dao.DAO;
import dao.DaoImpl;
import model.User;
import view.HomeView;
import view.LoginView;
import view.ProfileView;
import view.StartView;

public class LoginController{
    
    private User user;
    private LoginView view;
    private ProfileView profView;
    
    public LoginController(User user, LoginView view) {
        this.user = user;
        this.view = view;
        addListener();
    }
    
    private void addListener() {
        this.view.setLoginListener(new LoginListener());
    }
    
    class LoginListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
            String name = view.getUserNameTextField().getText();
            String pass = view.getUserPassTextField().getText();        
            DAO myDAO = new DaoImpl(view, profView);    
            try {
                //when method from DAOImpl get filled, proceed to Home
                if(myDAO.getUserLogIn(name, pass) != null) {
                    showHome();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void showHome() {
        HomeView home = new HomeView();
        home.setVisible(true);
        HomeController h = new HomeController(home);
        try {
            addUserDatatoView();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    

    public ArrayList<User> addUserDatatoView() throws SQLException {
        DAO myDAO = new DaoImpl(view, profView);
        ArrayList<User> userCredentials = myDAO.getUserLogIn(user.getUserName(), user.getUserPass());
        for(User us : userCredentials) {
            System.out.println("Directly from Controller: " + us);
        }
        return userCredentials;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and mark the line that throws the exception (LoginController line 75). I am guessing that the exception is cause by `user` being null in `myDAO.getUserLogIn(user.getUserName()`.  If so it seems that `LoginController` was initialized with a null value (`new LoginController(null, view)`). For more help post [mre]

Comment: Basically, you want the controller to be the center point and orchestrate the whole thing: get user details from the `view`, use `dao` to verify it (dao should be independent of view. It should not have a reference to the view) and update the view according to the results of the verification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to tell from the partial code in the question, but from what I see, a `User` object can be constructed only after a successful login. so the constructor should change to:

```
public LoginController(LoginView view) {
    this.view = view;
    addListener();
}
```

And

```
class LoginListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
        String name = view.getUserNameTextField().getText();
        String pass = view.getUserPassTextField().getText();        
        DAO myDAO = new DaoImpl(view, profView);    
        try {
            user = myDAO.getUserLogIn(name, pass);//change getUserLogIn to return a single User, or null 
            //when method from DAOImpl get filled, proceed to Home
            if(user != null) {                
                showHome();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```